# Laravel Eloquent Model return data if relatioship has data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Good day, I'm trying to return data from Eloquent Model with relationships.
Is there a way to ( skip / not return) orders where relationship returns an empty array as result?

[image]

```
 Order::with(['products' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('progress', function ($query) {
            $query->where('progress_id', 30)->orWhereBetween('progress_id', [60, 90]);
        });
        $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
            $query->where('vendor_id', 3);
        })->with(['product' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'identifier', 'reference', 'shipping_id');
        }]);
        $query->select('id', 'order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity');
    }])
        ->whereHas('products')
        ->where('status_id', '=', 15)
        ->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orders.created_at')
        ->get();
```

So in this case I don't want to get that order because there are no products with it.
Also I don't understand why am I even getting results there are orders with status_id = 15 but non for vendor_id = 3.
How to do it? Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Order::whereHas('products')->with(['products' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('progress', function ($query) {
            $query->where('progress_id', 30)->orWhereBetween('progress_id', [60, 90]);
        });
        $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
            $query->where('vendor_id', 3);
        })->with(['product' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('id', 'identifier', 'reference', 'shipping_id');
        }]);
        $query->select('id', 'order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity');
    }])->where('status_id', '=', 15)
        ->select('orders.id', 'orders.customer_id', 'orders.created_at')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Hello Hammad Khan thank you for your response that doesn't work I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this code:

```
Order::has('product', '>=', 1)->get();
```

Comment: Hello R.tbr thank you for your response. When I run just that part I do get two of my orders that contain products. Order::has('products', '>=', 1)->get();

Comment: Hi.What do you mean?Maybe you only have two order with this condition ('product', '>=', 1)

Comment: Well if I call Order::has('products', '>=', 1)->get(); its going to return me Orders that have 1 or more products that have been order. Order hasMany products is the relationship

Comment: Order::has('product', '>=', 1)->with('products')->get();

Comment: I do not fully understand what you mean.But maybe the top code is useful

Comment: I can't reference product. I have orders and they contain products like what's been ordered and products have a product relationship which is the parent that describes the product img, size etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
Order::whereHas('products' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereHas('progress', function ($query) {
            $query->where('progress_id', 30)->orWhereBetween('progress_id', [60, 90]);
        });
        $query->whereHas('product', function ($query) {
            $query->where('vendor_id', 3);
        });
        // $query->select('id', 'order_id', 'product_id', 'quantity'); // This line will cause error
    }])->with(['products', 'products.product:id,identifier,reference,shipping_id,vendor_id'])
       ->where('status_id', 15)
       ->get();
```

Comment: Hello maki10 thank you for your response. I have tried your snippet it works in case when there is no existing vendor! I do have the error that the query returns both products even if one of them is not with progress 30 or between 60-90. In case of both products failing to have the proper progress than it will not return the order which is great. Looks like that the where progress_id part is not correctly applying the logic to individual products. How to do it? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. Let's try simple and show me where I am wrong.
What above `query` will do:
1. Give me all *Orders* where has *Products* and `Status_id` is 15
2. Filter that *Products* by `progress`, if has one, where `progress_id` is 30 `orWhere` is between..
3. Filter that *Products* by `product`, if has one, where `vendor_id` is 3
4. Eager load `product` by selecting `id,identifier,reference,shipping_id`

Also try this `})->with(['product:id,identifier,reference,shipping_id,vendor_id']);`

Comment: It's alright it is a challenge definitely. The query doesn't load the products.product this part: ->with(['product:id,identifier,reference,shipping_id,vendor_id']); also it will return the order with all products even if some have not the correct progress_id.

Comment: And if you remove all Eager loads? `with(['products'])` and `->with(['product:id,identifier,reference,shipping_id,vendor_id'])`

Comment: In that case it will return me just the order nothing else.

Comment: Strange, one odd question, are you sure that you have Orders with Products?

Comment: I do have them. Order hasMany Products and Products BelongTo Product also Product has one Progress. It is so strange all I want is to get the proper products by progress. I don't understand if Laravel can't filter them out. It fails when there is more then one order product. It returns all order products regardless of the specific progress_id until there is at least one with the right progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219549/discussion-between-maki10-and-baltazar).

Comment: Okay let us do that.